# How do I use a static method as the target of CallMethodAction?

Tags: wpf, xaml

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
 <Button Content="Status">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="ResetStatus" TargetObject="{StaticResource Domain.Adapters.IIS}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
```

throws an exception on launch. Can `CallMethodAction` call static methods?

Comment: Can't you just wrap the static method? If it is static it should be accessible via the DataContext object (what you are binding to) or even the code behind (might not be the best place for it but possible). Just a thought.

Comment: that's not really the point, of course you can just wrap it, but if it is not necessary, then why do extra work just because we don't know the built-in way to do it?

Comment: Agreed. That is why I commented but didn't try to answer.